# Install a Private Google Sheets add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, add-on

I have a Google Sheets add-on published privately (only those with link can install) on domain 1 (G Suite Business).

I tested on domain 2 (G Suite Business) and it installed (although I get the unverified app message which is fine).  No problem here.

I asked a friend to test on his domain which is a G Suite Education domain and it would not install, got an error message:

[image]
What setting does the Google domain admin (for Education) have to turn on to allow this add-on to install?  Is this specific to Education domains?

Comment: Which services uses your addon? Is your friend the G Suite superadmin of their domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I missed a setting, Chrome store was set to off, which is weird because users could install from store but not the private add-on.  This and manually allowing all the scopes for the add-on seemed to have fixed the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is off the top of my head, I had the same problem once. The problem is if you have gmail domain it will work but for the other domains if that domain is using [gsuit](https://gsuite.google.com/) then the administrator has to allow using the add-ons from the admin panel. If that educational domain is using some other services e.g from Microsoft's etc. then you don't have google apps.

For Gsuit have a look at [Enable add-ons in Docs editor](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4530135?hl=en)

Comment: users on domain 3 can install add-ons that are published in the Chrome Store however they cannot install privately published add-ons. All of the domains i used are G Suite. Enable add-ons in Docs editor is turned on in domain 3.

Comment: hmm I would guess if you are sharing the link of the privately published addon and if the domain 3 has the right settings then it should work.. maybe someone else can provide insight on this case.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the G Suite for Education are the same of G Suite Business so it could be that the problem is due to the specific organization setup or to the setup of the organizational unit of your friends account.

The specific settings that should be turn on to allow add-ons are described on [Enable add-ons in Docs editors](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4530135?hl=en).

Reference

- [Compare G Suite Editions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6043385?hl=en)

Comment: We tried the allow add on to be installed option. That’s not it. There has to be some other security setting specific to this domain

Comment: It's very likely that you are missing some setting. Consider to add screenshots of the domain's Drive & Docs settings to the Developing add-ons for G Suite Community as this looks as sys admin rather than a programming question.